# Как вывести false если все массивы пусты?

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

У меня есть массив с объектами, внутри каждого объекта есть еще массив. Функция должна выводить false, если в каждом объекте есть пустой массив.

```js
items = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: "Group 1",
    items: [
      { id: 'group1_item1', value: 'Title 1' },
      { id: 'group1_item2', value: 'Title 2' },
      { id: 'group1_item3', value: 'Title 3' },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: "Group 2",
    items: [
      { id: 'group2_item1', value: 'Title 4' },
      { id: 'group2_item2', value: 'Title 5' },
      { id: 'group2_item3', value: 'Title 6' },
    ]
  },
]
```

Использую такую функцию, но она возвращает false в любом случае, если хоть один массив пуст, а другой нет, а нужно только если все массивы пусты. Возможно дико туплю и ответ перед глазами, но застрял на три дня уже( ХЭЛП!

```js
   function getResultSearch() {
let result;
const isEmpty = resultItems => !Object.values(resultItems).every(({ length }) => length);
for (let el of resultItems) {
  result = el.items
}
return isEmpty (result)
  }
```

Comment: Тебе стоит копнуть в рекурсию.

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду? Рекурсия должна происходить в какой момент?

Comment: Всегда. В вашем слкчае нужно проверить массив на наличие элементов. Потом, если они есть, то вызвать этот же метод для каждого из элементов внутри. При каждом вызове проверять, что вернул метод, если true, значит идти дальше, если false, то вернуть false. Так у вас рекурсия пройдет по всем, но при этом вернет false сразу, как только условие не будет выполнено.

Comment: звучит разумно. Я с рекурсиями никогда не работал. Если не сложно, есть возможность пример кода написать? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

С ходу можно такое придумать без рекурсии.

```js
let items = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: "Group 1",
    items: [
      { id: 'group1_item1', value: 'Title 1' },
      { id: 'group1_item2', value: 'Title 2' },
      { id: 'group1_item3', value: 'Title 3' },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: "Group 2",
    items: [
      { id: 'group2_item1', value: 'Title 4' },
      { id: 'group2_item2', value: 'Title 5' },
      { id: 'group2_item3', value: [ ] },
    ]
  },
]

let items1 =
  {
    id: '1',
    title: "Group 1",
    items: [
    ]
  }



let checkObjectForEmptyArray = (obj) => {
  let stringifiedObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
  return !stringifiedObj.includes('[') ? false : stringifiedObj.replaceAll('[]', '').includes("[")
}

console.log(checkObjectForEmptyArray(items));
console.log(checkObjectForEmptyArray(items1));
```

Comment: Благодарю, но такой вариант не подойдет. В функцию не дожен передаваться параметром массив. Ведь он должен проверить все массивы внутри только родительского массива items

Comment: @Евгений Почему вы решили что передаётся массив?

Comment: @Евгений в любом случае тут идея важна а не то что вы передаёте